# How to convert a List into DataTable

Tags: c#, list, ado.net, datatable, datarow

I'm getting values from another data table as input to list. Now i need to save those list values into another DataTable.

List:

```
List<DataRow> list = slectedFieldsTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
foreach (DataRow dr in slectedFieldsTable.Rows)
{
    list.Add(dr);
}
```

New Data table :

```
DataRow newRow = tempTable.NewRow();
newRow["Field Name"] = fieldLabel;
newRow["Field Type"] = fieldType;

for(int gg =0 ; gg<list.Count; gg++)
{
    tempTable.Rows.Add(????);
}
```

I'm stuck here in adding up rows in to new data table.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable

Answer (score 12):

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
           var values = new object[Props.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
           {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
           }
           dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
      }
      //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
      return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Variable declare:

```
    DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable slectedFieldsTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow newRow;
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
```

Add Column in DataTable:

```
    slectedFieldsTable = new DataTable();
    slectedFieldsTable.Columns.Add("Field Name");
    slectedFieldsTable.Columns.Add("Field Type");
```

Add Value in DataTable:

```
    slectedFieldsTable.Rows.Add("1", "AAA");
    slectedFieldsTable.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");
    slectedFieldsTable.Rows.Add("3", "CCC");
```

Convert DataTable to List:

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in slectedFieldsTable.Rows)
    {
        list.Add(dr);
    }
```

Add Column in another DataTable:

```
    tempTable.Columns.Add("Field Name", typeof(string));
    tempTable.Columns.Add("Field Type", typeof(string));
```

Convert List to dataTable:

```
   foreach(DataRow dr in list)
    {
        newRow = tempTable.NewRow();
        newRow["Field Name"] = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        newRow["Field Type"] = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
        tempTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        tempTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use CopyToDataTable() method.  [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = TempselectedFieldsTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer providing the `ToDataTable` is a very nice start but it is missing some key elements.  Namely, it ignores that `List` item properties may:

- ...be marked `ReadOnly`
- ...use the `DisplayName` attribute
- ...have a `DefaultValue` which the `DataColumn` should know about
- ...be `Nullable`
- ...be marked `BrowsableAttribute(false)`

The following is an extension method to return a `DataTable` and either accounts for the above or provides the means for your code to apply them. It also uses an `Interface` to  get the values from the class object rather than `Reflection`.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> lst, bool includeAll = true)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc;
    PropertyDescriptor pd;
    bool Browsable;

    PropertyDescriptorCollection propCol = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    for (int n = 0; n < propCol.Count; n++)
    {
        pd = propCol[n];
        Type propT = pd.PropertyType;

        dc = new DataColumn(pd.Name);

        // if Nullable, get underlying type
        // the first test may not be needed
        if (propT.IsGenericType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propT) != null )
        {
            propT = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propT);
            dc.DataType = propT;
            dc.AllowDBNull = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dc.DataType = propT;
            dc.AllowDBNull = false;
        }

        // is it readonly?
        if (pd.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)] != null)
        {
            dc.ReadOnly = ((ReadOnlyAttribute)pd.
                     Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)]).IsReadOnly;
        }         

        // DefaultValue ...
        if (pd.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)] != null)
        {
            dc.DefaultValue = ((DefaultValueAttribute)pd.
                   Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)]).Value;
        }

        // caption / display name
        dc.ExtendedProperties.Add("DisplayName", dc.Caption);
        if (pd.Attributes[typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)] != null)
        {
            // these are usually present but blank
            string theName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)pd.
                   Attributes[typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)]).DisplayName;
            dc.Caption = string.IsNullOrEmpty(theName) ? dc.Caption : theName;
            // DGV doesnt use Caption...save for later
            dc.ExtendedProperties["DisplayName"] = dc.Caption;
        }

        Browsable = true;
        dc.ExtendedProperties.Add("Browsable", Browsable);
        var foo = pd.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
        if (pd.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)] != null) 
        {
            Browsable = ((BrowsableAttribute)pd.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)]).Browsable;
            // no such thing as a NonBrowsable DataColumn
            dc.ExtendedProperties["Browsable"] = Browsable;
        }

        // ToDo: add support for custom attributes

        if (includeAll || Browsable)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        }
    }

    // the lst could be empty such as creating a typed table
    if (lst.Count == 0) return dt;

    if (lst[0] is IDataValuesProvider)
    {
        IDataValuesProvider dvp;
        // copy the data - let the class do the work
        foreach (T item in lst)
        {
            dvp = (IDataValuesProvider)item;
            dt.Rows.Add(dvp.GetDataValues(includeAll).ToArray());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        List<object> values;
        foreach (T item in lst)
        {
            values =  new List<object>();
            // only Browsable columns added
            for (int n = 0; n < dt.Columns.Count; n++)
            {
                 values.Add(propCol[dt.Columns[n].ColumnName].GetValue(item));
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
        }
    }   

    return dt;
}
```

The method allows you to specify whether columns for non `Browsable` properties should be added to the `DataTable`.  Rather than hiding the columns later, you can omit them entirely if you want.

An interface proves the means to get the data values from collection members in order (as an alternative to a reflection loop):

```
public interface IDataValuesProvider
{
    IEnumerable<object> GetDataValues(bool includeAll);
}

... on the class:
public class StockItem : IDataValuesProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
    [Browsable(false), DisplayName("Ignore")]
    public string propA {get; set;}
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Zone { get; set; }
    public string Size {get; set;}
    [DisplayName("Nullable")]
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
    public int OnHand {get; set;}
    public string ProdCode {get; set;}
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string propB { get; set; }
    public DateTime ItemDate {get; set;}

    // IDataValuesProvider implementation
    public IEnumerable<object> GetDataValues(bool IncludeAll)
    {
        List<object> values = new List<object>();

        values.AddRange(new object[] {Id, ItemName });
        if (IncludeAll) values.Add(propA);

        values.AddRange(new object[] { Zone, Size, Foo, OnHand, ProdCode });
        if (IncludeAll) values.Add(propB);

        values.Add(ItemDate);

        return values;
    }
}
```

Add the data values in the same order as they are listed in your class; be sure to update it when you add properties. The reflection version is still there so you can do it either way.

Finally, there are a few common `Attribute`s which do not have a related `DataColumn` property.  The method stores these for you as `ExtendedProperties` allowing you to easily apply them to the DGV:

```
var dtX = someData.ToDataTable();

dgvB.SuspendLayout();
dgvB.DataSource = dtX;

// process extended props
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtX.Columns)
{
    // no need to test, the code adds them everytime
    //if (dc.ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey("DisplayName"))
    //{ 
        dgvB.Columns[dc.ColumnName].HeaderText = dc.ExtendedProperties["DisplayName"].ToString(); 
    //}
    //if (dc.ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey("Browsable"))
    //{
        dgvB.Columns[dc.ColumnName].Visible = (bool)dc.ExtendedProperties["Browsable"];
    //}
}
dgvB.ResumeLayout();
```

Results using a list of the class shown above:

[image]

Both `OnHand` and `Foo` show the `DisplayName` and both `PropA` and `PropB` are hidden.  Most importantly, columns created for `ReadOnly` and `Nullable` properties act accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
     foreach (DataRow dr in list)
     {
        tempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
```