# List to DataTable extension

Tags: c#, list, datatable, datarow

Hi I am writing an extension method that converts list to datatable.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        int columns = properties.Count();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //set the column count in this list
            table.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach(var element in list)
        {                                
            table.Rows.Add(element);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Here Some column values might be null. How can i correctly map each value to table.Rows

Currently its trying to convert a list element to a column...i get error

> Unable to cast object of type 'PracticeContractsListDTO' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store PracticeContractsListDTO in
>   PracticeContractId Column.  Expected type is Int64.

Can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Its already been done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15128140/1070452

Comment: Use Mark Gravells FastMember - its by far the best implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable