# How to use the generic method with the type to convert a List of lists of objects to several DataTables?

Tags: c#, list, datatable, data-conversion, jagged-arrays

I have a genetic method that converst the list to datatable.

```
public static DataTable CreateTable<T>(IList<T> items){
    ....
    ...
}
```

So I have a list that has different type of items in.

```
var myList = new List<IList>{
    new List<A>(),
    new List<B>(),
    new List<C>(),
    ..
    ..
}
```

I want to convert this list to datatables using foreach.

```
foreach(var item in myList){
    var table = CreateTable(???)
}
```

But CreateTable method is generic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/) and [How to convert a list into data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100783/) and [How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/) and [How to convert a List into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128140/)

Comment: Do you mean that each entry in `myList` represents a column in your resulting `DataTable`?

Comment: Your function takes IList<T>, but you supply IList without defined type (T). You could make A B and C inherit a base class, ABCBase, and initialize var myList = List<IList<ABCBase>> ...