# C# convert model object to Datatable

Tags: c#, sql, json, datatable, webapi

I have a .Net application which is calling a WebAPI

The WebApi response is a JsonString:

```
{
     "total" : 50,
     "users" : [
         {
            "id" : "abc123",
            "firstName" : "First1",
            "lastName" : "Last1",
            "roles" : [
                 "admin"
             ]
         },
         {
            "id" : "abc124",
            "firstName" : "First2",
            "lastName" : "Last2",
            "roles" : [
                 "admin",
                 "normal"
             ]
         },
         ...... so on
      ]
 }
```

This is my model classes:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
     public int total { get; set; }
     public List<Users> users { get; set; }
     public ApiResponse()
     {
          users = new List<Users>();
     }
}

public class Users
{
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string firstName { get; set; }
     public string lastName{ get; set; }
     public List<string> roles { get; set; } 
}
```

I am converting the JsonString response from web api to my model object:

```
 var response = myObj.CallRestAPI("url");
 ApiResponse data = (ApiResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeOf(ApiResponse));
```

How do I convert this model object data to datatable to like below: -- to save in SQL database

```
id      firstName    lastName    roles
abc123  first1       last1       admin
abc124  first2       last2       admin, normal
```

or is there a way to convert the jsonString directly to datatable?

I tried to convert the jsonString to Datatable:

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(response);
DataTable dt = jObject["users"].ToObject<DataTable>();
```

But the resulting datatable is :

```
id      firstName    lastName    roles
abc123  first1       last1       **System.String[]**
abc124  first2       last2       **System.String[]**
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code you have, you could add another column:

```
    public class Users
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("roles")] //put this attribute to bind this with roles from json
        public List<string> listRoles { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]  //to ignore this property coming from the json
        public string roles //add this new calculate column
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join(',',listRoles);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code, `listRoles` will contain the data converted from the json string into the `Users` class, then you will have an extra column `roles` that column will cotain the list of `listRoles` separate by `','`,  and I think you can remove the column `listRoles` from the resulting `DataTable`

Update: This is to generate the data you need for your table, next you can convert List to DataTable you can check this response for that: [Convert list to datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128140/how-to-convert-a-list-into-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse your json at first

```
var usersParsed = JObject.Parse(response)["users"];
    
    //flatten roles to a string
    foreach (var item in usersParsed)
        item["roles"] = string.Join(",", item["roles"].ToObject<string[]>());


    DataTable dataTable = usersParsed.ToObject<DataTable>();
```